# Why does VideoView require leaving the activity then resuming it to play a video file?

Tags: android, android-videoview

This is a very weird problem.  I know that I probably miss something fundamental, but I could not find any explanation after diligent search. 
The weird problem is the following:

1. An app generates a video file (foo.mp4).
2. It starts another activity to play this file (see code below).
3. The video play file play activity displays error message: "Can't play this video"
4. Leave this activity (e.g. by tapping the home key).
5. Go back to the app, and the video plays perfectly.

The above is 100% reproducible. 
The following is the code (this is not the production code, but it is the actual code used to reproduce the problem.)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video_file);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setVideoPath(getIntent().getStringExtra("file_path"));
}

protected void onResume() {
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.start();
    super.onResume();
};
```

The file path is: /storage/sdcard0/Movies/MyApp/foo.mp4

Some may think at this point that a waiting period is needed before playing after the file is created. I have tried waiting for 2 minutes after the file's writing stream is closed and before the video file play activity is started.  The outcome is exactly the same.

Comment: Not really a solution to your problem, but what happens if you set a onPreparedListener to your videoView and only plays afterwards? Additionally, can you check if the "file_path" changes between the first and second start of the activity?

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I have tried it, but unfortunately it still requires leaving the activity then coming back. onCreate() is not called when the activity is resumed after switching to others, so the URI remains the same.

Comment: Any reason you re-instantiate the VideoView on the onResume() method?

Comment: No, VideoView is not reinstantiated. It is in the layout file.  Both onCreate and onResume() just get a reference to it.